# Changing how letters show when there are duplications in recreating Wordle

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have just starting learning python and am trying to make Wordle. This is what I have done so far with 'gWs' being the variable for the guessed word split into a list with each letter of the word being an item in the list. 'cWs' is the same as 'gWs' but for the correct word which is randomly selected. The code compares whether each letter of both words are the same, in the word or not in the word. I can't figure how to make it so that if the word guessed has 2 or more of the same letter and the correct word only has one of the those letters, then it outputs that one letter is in the word or in the correct spot, and then the other is not in the word.

```
    if gWs[0] == cWs[0]:
        print('[' + gWs[0] + ']', end=' ')
    elif gWs[0] in cWs:
        print('|' + gWs[0] + '|', end=' ')
    elif gWs[0] in cWs:
        print('|' + gWs[0] + '|', end=' ')
    else:
        print('{' + gWs[0] + '}', end=' ')
    
    if gWs[1] == cWs[1]:
        print('[' + gWs[1] + ']', end=' ')
    elif gWs[1] in cWs:
        print('|' + gWs[1] + '|', end=' ')
    else:
        print('{' + gWs[1] + '}', end=' ')
    
    if gWs[2] == cWs[2]:
        print('[' + gWs[2] + ']', end=' ')
    elif gWs[2] in cWs:
        print('|' + gWs[2] + '|', end=' ')
    else:
        print('{' + gWs[2] + '}', end=' ')
    
    if gWs[3] == cWs[3]:
        print('[' + gWs[3] + ']', end=' ')
    elif gWs[3] in cWs:
        print('|' + gWs[3] + '|', end=' ')
    else:
        print('{' + gWs[3] + '}', end=' ')
    
    if gWs[4] == cWs[4]:
        print('[' + gWs[4] + ']')
    elif gWs[4] in cWs:
        print('|' + gWs[4] + '|')
    else:
        print('{' + gWs[4] + '}')
```

Thanks.

Comment: I personally don't like looking at 15 print statements

Comment: what should i do instead?

Comment: @StephenAlkalineIs there a reason you're not using a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, use better variable names - there is no negative to use *words* instead of *3-letter-acronyms*.

Then change your code so it uses loops and enumerate for the checks.

Put the checking into a function to reuse - return the build string.
Don't print with `end=""` - instead collect parts in a list and `.join()` them before returning.

```
def yours_fixed(correctWord, guess):
    # loop instead of if - elif - elif - elif for each letter position
    result = []
    for pos,letter in enumerate(guess):
        if letter == correctWord[pos]:
            result.append(f"[{letter}]")
        elif letter in correctWord:
            result.append(f"|{letter}|")
        else:
            result.append(f"{{{letter}}}")

    return " ".join(result)
```

Then think about what you want:

- somehow count letters
- if letter resolves, remove 1 from the count and delete if counts are 0
- do the check and print with the counting dict not against the word

```
def better_checkWords(correctWord, guess):
    # use collection.Counter to get the same but more effective
    letterCount = {a: correctWord.count(a) for a in set(correctWord)}
    def removeLetter(l):
        if letter in letterCount:
            letterCount[letter] -= 1
            if letterCount[letter] == 0:
                del letterCount[letter]

    result = []
    for pos,letter in enumerate(guess):

        if letter == correctWord[pos]:
            result.append(f"[{letter}]")
            removeLetter(letter)
        elif letter in letterCount:  # check if letter still in
            result.append(f"|{letter}|")
            removeLetter(letter)
        else:
            result.append(f"{{{letter}}}")

    return " ".join(result)

correctWord = "aabcd"
guess = "abaax"
print( yours_fixed(correctWord, guess))
print( better_checkWords(correctWord, guess))
```

Output:

```
# "aabcd" correct
# "abaax" guessed

[a] |b| |a| |a| {x}  # yours
[a] |b| |a| {a} {x}  # better one
```

Comment: Thanks for helpful pointers! I definitely need to continue my python course further to understand this but for now I have implemented it into my code and it works great!

Comment: When the guess word is 'payee', the code fails and says:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\zepha\mu_code\programs\wordle2.0.py", line 77, in <module>
    print(checkWords(correctWord, guessWord))
  File "c:\users\zepha\mu_code\programs\wordle2.0.py", line 24, in checkWords
    removeLetter(letter)
  File "c:\users\zepha\mu_code\programs\wordle2.0.py", line 17, in removeLetter
    letterCount[letter] -= 1
KeyError: 'e'

Comment: @StephenAlkaline hopefully fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `gWs` has more than one of letter `l`, and `cWs` has exactly one `l`. You can do something like

```
flag = [0] * len(gWs)
for i, x in enumerate(gWs):
    if x == l:
        if i == cWs.index(x):
            flag[i] = 2
        else:
            flag[i] = 1
```

Now according to `flag`:

0 - not in `cWs`

1 - in `cWs` but not at the right position

2 - at the right position